# xjc generates incorrect jaxb annotations for collection of IDREF elements

Tags: xml, xsd, jaxb, xjc, jaxb2-annotate-plugin

TL;DR:
The code and annotations generated by xjc + jaxb2-annotate + xew does not produce the desired (or, for that matter, working out-of-the-box) xml structure, which should be a collection of IDREF elements.

If I manually change the jaxb attributes on the collection in the generated code, it works as I expect.

What is generated is:

```
    @XmlElementWrapper(required = true)  // from xew
    @XmlElementRef(name = "investigator", namespace = "http://example/test", type = JAXBElement.class)
    protected List<PersonType> investigators;
```

What I want is:

```
@XmlElementWrapper(required = true)  // from xew
@XmlElement(name = "investigator", required = true, type = Object.class)
@XmlIDREF
@XmlSchemaType(name = "IDREF")
protected List<PersonType> investigators;
```

The generated annotations throw an exception at runtime saying PersonType does not have XmlRootElement.  If I add that, it will run, but the XML collection is incorrect, having <person_type> elements instead of <investigfator> elements.

My question is how to get xjc to generate (what I consider to be the "correct") annotations?

---

Given the this schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://example/test"
  xmlns="http://example/test" elementFormDefault="qualified" >

  <xs:element name="test_metadata" type="test_document_type"/>

  <xs:complexType name="test_document_type">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="investigators" > 
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="investigator" type="xs:IDREF" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="dataSubmitter" type="xs:IDREF" />
      <xs:element name="people">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="person" type="person_type" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="person_type"  id="ref_id">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element name="organization" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element name="contactInfo" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element name="identifier" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" nillable="true" />
      <xs:element name="link" type="xs:anyURI" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="ref_id" type="xs:ID" use="required"/>
  </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```

and these xjc binding customizations:

```
<jaxb:bindings node="xs:complexType[@name='test_document_type']//xs:element[@name='investigators']//xs:element[@name='investigator']">
      <jaxb:property>
        <jaxb:baseType name="PersonType"/>
      </jaxb:property>
    </jaxb:bindings>
    <jaxb:bindings node="xs:complexType[@name='test_document_type']//xs:element[@name='dataSubmitter']">
      <jaxb:property>
        <jaxb:baseType name="PersonType"/>
      </jaxb:property>
    </jaxb:bindings>
```

The (relevant) generated code is:

```
public class TestDocumentType implements Serializable
{
    @XmlElementWrapper(required = true)
    @XmlElementRef(name = "investigator", namespace = "http://example/test", type = JAXBElement.class)
    protected List<PersonType> investigators;
    @XmlElement(required = true, type = Object.class)
    @XmlIDREF
    @XmlSchemaType(name = "IDREF")
    protected PersonType dataSubmitter;
    @XmlElementWrapper(required = true)
    @XmlElement(name = "person", namespace = "http://example/test")
    protected List<xml.test.PersonType> people;
}
```

Notice the `@XmlElementRef(name = "investigator", namespace = "http://example/test", type = JAXBElement.class)`

When I use this generated code to build a Java object with a couple of <investigator> people and a <dataSubmitter> person (all also in the <people> collection), and then try serialize that using jaxb, the `missing an @XmlRootElement annotation` exception mentioned above is thrown.

Now if I manually change the annotations on the 
`List<PersonType> investigators` field to

```
@XmlElement(name = "investigator", required = true, type = Object.class)
@XmlIDREF
@XmlSchemaType(name = "IDREF")
protected List<PersonType> investigators;
```

and run the code, I get the expected collection of IDREF elements:

```
<test_metadata xmlns="http://example/test">
    <investigators>
        <investigator>JohnHDoe</investigator>
        <investigator>JackSmith</investigator>
    </investigators>
    <dataSubmitter>JohnHDoe</dataSubmitter>
    <people>
        <person ref_id="JohnHDoe">
            <name>John H Doe</name>
            <organization>semi</organization>
            <contactInfo>tweedy</contactInfo>
        </person>
        <person ref_id="JackSmith">
            <name>Jack Smith</name>
            <organization>fully</organization>
            <contactInfo>whistler</contactInfo>
        </person>
    </people>
</test_metadata>
```

Is there some control or binding customization that I need to correct jaxb annotations on the collection?  Or another way to get the same XML structure?

Thanks

Comment: Currently I have a work-around in which I manually add all the desired annotations, and then post-process the file to remove the XmlElementRef and JAXBElement stuff.  annox:removeAnnotation does not work, claiming that there is not XmlElementRef annotation on the given element.